# Python create a list of X elements where the elements count by Y. For example, if X = 4 and Y = 5 you'd receive [5, 10, 15, 20]

Tags: python

This is what I have tried so far:

```py
x = 4
y = 5
z = []
for i in range(x):
    i=i*y
    z.append(i)
```

But my output is showing: [0, 5, 10, 15]

How do I get indexing to start on 5 and go to 20?

Comment: simply add +1 to your range `range(1, x + 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem you are having is the range of numbers you are generating:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> list(range(x))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Just change

```
range(1, x + 1)
```

And see the documentation for [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Answer (score 1):

Using only the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) method you can generate your list.

`z = list(range(y, x*y + 1, y))`

Answer (score 0):

You can add one to `i`

```
x = 4
y = 5
z = []
for i in range(x):
    i=(i+1)*y
    z.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension as well.

```
x = 4
y = 5
z = [y + i * y for i in range(x)]
```